# FatalErrorException: Class 'form' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1. I am following a tutorial that is made in Laravel 5. I am working with form but it's not working properly.

I'm facing this error:

> FatalErrorException in 44a7f556a7d1beef3d09ba2ba2e3c7f0 line 7: Class 'form' not found

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Update composer.json (require part)

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
```

Run command , to update

```
composer update
```

Add to providers array

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Add to aliases array

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: that is   [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'  
   not found in /var/www/html/new-blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminat  
  e/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146

Comment: These are 3 steps, first write package name, 2nd composer update, 3rd update in app.php, I think you mixed 1st and 3rd.